# Adding Headers while aggregation a dataFrame with selective columns in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a dataFrame with three columns namely `'Ts_id'`,`'doc_id'`,`'doc_type'` on which I am finding the count aggregating on only `'doc_id'` and `'doc_type'`. But when I am writing the aggregated value into a CSV, 'Ts_id' is also coming as a header. i.e. i am receiving four headers now as `'Ts_id'`,`'doc_id'`,`'doc_type'` and `'count'` where `'Ts_Id'` column is blank and unnecessary. Is there a way i can rename the columns or add different headers post aggregating?
The piece of code is provided below:

```
dfnonreturns = pd.DataFrame(GuidedocdetailsNonReturn,columns=['Ts_id','doc_id','doc_type'])
dfnonreturnguidecount = dfnonreturns.groupby(['doc_id','doc_type']).agg(['count'])
dfnonreturnguidecount.to_csv('NonReturn_guideid_counts.csv',header=True)
```

Python Version is 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
dfnonreturns = pd.DataFrame(GuidedocdetailsNonReturn,columns=['Ts_id','doc_id','doc_type'])
dfnonreturnguidecount = dfnonreturns[['doc_id','doc_type']].groupby(['doc_id','doc_type']).agg(['count'])
dfnonreturnguidecount.to_csv('NonReturn_guideid_counts.csv',header=True)
```

Comment: Nope..dosen't works gives "in_aggregate_multiple_funcs raise ValueError("no results")."

Comment: Easier solution is to add `dfnonreturnguidecount.drop(['Ts_id'], axis=1, inplace=True) ` before writing it to_csv.